# DocuSign: Display Quote PDFs

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a custom DocuSign button in Salesforce standard Quote object. It is working well. However, when I am trying to add documents, I do not see Quote PDFs. Is there a way to include this list?

Comment: Please include an example of code that doesn't work. Additionally, information about what you have tried and why it doesn't quite do what you want would be beneficial. Until this information is added, I am recommending that this question be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, you should review the DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Administrator_Guide.pdf) -- specifically content starting on page 16 under the heading **Adding Send With DocuSign Button to the Quotes Object**.  It includes several custom button code examples. The release notes for DfS v4.1.17 (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignForSalesforceReleaseNotesv4.1.17.pdf) also contain some sample custom button code for sending from the Quote object.